# Calculation of wage based on inputs in python

Tags: python

I have a python problem and I can't seem to get to the finish line with this question for homework. Basically, the problem is:

- an employee's wage is $36.25p/h. a normal working week is 37 hours.
- if he works more than 37 hours he gets paid 1.5 times the normal rate ($54.375)
- if the employee sells 6 cars or more a week he receives a bonus of $200 per car sold.

> TASK: Write a program that takes as input the number of hours worked and the total number of cars sold for the week, and outputs the car dealer’s total salary for the week.

Here is the code I have so far:

```py
hours = int(input("How many hours were worked?"))
salary = float(input("The salary"))
cars = int(input("Total number of cars sold for the week?"))
total = hours * float(salary)
    
if hours > 37 and cars > 5:
    print("The salary is:",int(cars) * int(200) / 10 + 1.5 * total )
elif hours <= 37:
    print("The salary is:",total)
```

Comment: You have some sample inputs and their outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
BASE_HOURS = 37
WAGE_MULTIPLIER = 1.5
CAR_SALES_BONUS = 200
BASE_WAGE_SALES = 5 # Updated after assignment adjustment in comments.

hours = int(input("How many hours were worked? > "))
wage = float(input("The wage > ")) 
cars = int(input("Total number of cars sold for the week? > "))

if hours > 37:
    total = BASE_HOURS * wage + (hours - BASE_HOURS) * (wage * WAGE_MULTIPLIER)

else:
    total = hours * wage

if cars > BASE_WAGE_SALES:
    total += CAR_SALES_BONUS * (cars - BASE_WAGE_SALES)

# ...
```

As you can see I took my freedom to **refactor the code** quite a bit to **improve structure & reduce code smell**. Furthermore some **variable names** like `salary` where quite **unfitting** if I've interpreted the sense behind the script correctly, as we're interested in the **hourly wage** of the person, **not his salary**.

Comment: @ Bialomazur that worked perfectly, thank you for taking the time to solve this and inform me of better naming of the variables

Comment: Just noticed the bonus of 200 isn't working properly, it is only adding 100 to the wage once. i need it to reflect a 200 bonus per car sold past 5 cars. ie( 7 cars sold would be 2 X bonus = 400 bonus.

Comment: @Yakob ok, I'll update the answer quickly.